# How to be notified when all futures in Future.compose chain succeeded?

Tags: kotlin, callback, vert.x

My application (typical REST server that calls other REST services internally) has two main classes to perform the bootstrapping procedure.

There is the **Application.kt class** that is supposed to configure the vertx instance itself and to register certain modules (jackson kotlin integration for example):

```
class Application(
    private val profileSetting: String? = System.getenv("ACTIVE_PROFILES"),
    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application::class.java)!!
) {

    fun bootstrap() {
        val profiles = activeProfiles()
        val meterRegistry = configureMeters()
        val vertx = bootstrapVertx(meterRegistry)

        vertx.deployVerticle(ApplicationBootstrapVerticle(profiles)) { startup ->
            if (startup.succeeded()) {
                logger.info("Application startup finished")
            } else {
                logger.error("Application startup failed", startup.cause())
                vertx.close()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In addition there is a **ApplicationBootstrapVerticle.kt class** that is supposed to deploy the different verticles in a defined order. Some of them in sequence, some of them in parallel:

```
class ApplicationBootstrapVerticle(
    private val profiles: List<String>,
    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApplicationBootstrapVerticle::class.java)
) : AbstractVerticle() {

    override fun start(startFuture: Future<Void>) {
        initializeApplicationConfig().compose {
            logger.info("Application configuration initialized")
            initializeScheduledJobs()
        }.compose {
            logger.info("Scheduled jobs initialized")
            initializeRestEndpoints()
        }.compose {
            logger.info("Http server started")
            startFuture
        }.setHandler { ar ->
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                startFuture.complete()
            } else {
                startFuture.fail(ar.cause())
            }
        }
    }

    private fun initializeApplicationConfig(): Future<String> {
        return Future.future<String>().also {
            vertx.deployVerticle(
                ApplicationConfigVerticle(profiles),
                it.completer()
            )
        }
    }

    private fun initializeScheduledJobs(): CompositeFuture {
        val stationsJob = Future.future<String>()
        val capabilitiesJob = Future.future<String>()

        return CompositeFuture.all(stationsJob, capabilitiesJob).also {
            vertx.deployVerticle(
                StationQualitiesVerticle(),
                stationsJob.completer()
            )
            vertx.deployVerticle(
                VideoCapabilitiesVerticle(),
                capabilitiesJob.completer()
            )
        }
    }

    private fun initializeRestEndpoints(): Future<String> {
        return Future.future<String>().also {
            vertx.deployVerticle(
                RestEndpointVerticle(dispatcherFactory = RouteDispatcherFactory(vertx)),
                it.completer()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the supposed way to bootstrap an application, if there is any. More important though, I am not sure if I understand the Future.compose mechanics correctly.

The application starts up successfully and I see all desired log messages except the

> Application startup finished

message. Also the following code is never called **in case of successs**:

```
}.setHandler { ar ->
    if (ar.succeeded()) {
       startFuture.complete()
    } else {
       startFuture.fail(ar.cause())
    }
}
```

In case of an failure though, for example when my application configuration files (yaml) cannot be parsed because there is an unknown field in the *destination* entity, the log message

> Application startup failed

appears in the logs and also the code above is invoked.

I am curious what is wrong with my composed futures chain. I thought that the handler would be called after the previous futures succeeded or one of them failed but I think it's only called in case of success.

**Update**

I suppose that an invocation of `startFuture.complete()` was missing. By adapting the start method, it finally worked:

```
override fun start(startFuture: Future<Void>) {
    initializeApplicationConfig().compose {
        logger.info("Application configuration initialized")
        initializeScheduledJobs()
    }.compose {
        logger.info("Scheduled jobs initialized")
        initializeRestEndpoints()
    }.compose {
        logger.info("Http server started")
        startFuture.complete()
        startFuture
    }.setHandler(
        startFuture.completer()
    )
}
```

I am not sure though, if this is the supposed way to handle this future chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me looks like this:

```
override fun start(startFuture: Future<Void>) {
    initializeApplicationConfig().compose {
        logger.info("Application configuration initialized")
        initializeScheduledJobs()
    }.compose {
        logger.info("Scheduled jobs initialized")
        initializeRestEndpoints()
    }.setHandler { ar ->
        if(ar.succeeded()) {
            logger.info("Http server started")
            startFuture.complete()
        } else {
            startFuture.fail(ar.cause())
        }
    }
}
```